Cannot connect to Oracle DBai23 with sqlcl and JDBC
I'm trying to connect with SQLCL: RELEASE=24.3.2.330.1718
to my local DB23ai on Windows 10 with the latest Instant Client and JDBC package
and getting the following error:

URL = jdbc:oracle:oci8:@(DESCRIPTION = ..
Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:23502407, Jdbc-OCI:23402405

Please let me know which JDBC version is expected for this SQLCL version and how can I install this.
Friedhold

It looks like you have a 23.4 client, that's not the latest. Latest would be 23.5 or even 23.6

Thanks, Jeff.
I have the instant client 23.6 and the ORACLE_HOME was not set to the instant client 23.6 path; it works now.
